# Having the same form fields in two different places

Tags: usability, interaction-design, navigation

I'm working on a project for an educational technology platform. Essentially, there's a set of 3 settings that are required to make an assignment a "common assessment":

**1.) "Is this assignment a common assessment?" (Yes or no)**

**2.) Subject of the assignment (required if the assignment is a common assessment)**

**3.) Grade of the assignment (required if the assignment is a common assessment)**

Currently, the above settings are only available if a user publishes the assignment to the library (which makes the assignment visible to other teachers). Through user research we've identified that the settings to make an assignment a common assessment should live elsewhere.

**My question is, is it alright to have the set of three settings live in two different places? If so, should I disable the settings in the publish to library page in order to ensure that users can only change them in one place yet are aware that they are publishing to the library with the right settings?**

In the case where the settings in the publish to library page are disabled, I've provided a link for them to change the settings elsewhere.

I've attached some screenshots below.

Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is this Common Setting for one user to his/her all assessment as a checkbox?

Comment: @Moksh Hi! I'm not sure I understand your question. This checkbox would be for each individual assignment.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It depends how often does the user do "Publish to Library" action, or in other words how intrusive this option will appear.

I would do next:

1. Leave that as option on Publish to library screen, but leave only Checkbox, which if checked then toggles two fields below. This way option doesnt takes much space or focus
2. Leave it in settings also, it doesn't matter if its available on two places. Pretty often in specific flows configuration setting is offered and explained that it can be later tweaked in settings of the app

Answer (score -1):

No, it is not recommended to place information multiple places.

We should assume scenarios like,

1. Common Assessment Setting fields grow large
2. Some private settings while publishing to a library gets introduced. So, space issue can occur.

I would suggest something like this:
[image: suggestion]